# read data from mongodb to spark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

am trying to read a collection in mongodb as a spark dataframe
this what i did , am using eclipse scala ide , and this what i did

```
 package TestMongoDB
 import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import com.mongodb.spark.sql._
import com.mongodb.spark._
import org.bson.Document
import com.mongodb.spark.config._
object MongoDB extends App {

try {
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
def makeMongoURI(uri:String,database:String,collection:String) = (s"${uri}/${database}.${collection}")

val mongoURI = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
val Conf = makeMongoURI(mongoURI,"io","thing")
val readConfigintegra: ReadConfig = ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> Conf))
// Uses the ReadConfig
 val df3 = sparkSession.sqlContext.loadFromMongoDB(ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/io.thing")))
 df3.printSchema()
      } catch {
        case t: Throwable => t.printStackTrace() // TODO: handle error
        println(t.getMessage)
      }

    }
```

i got the error below

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions$Builder.<init>(MongoClientOptions.java:758)
    at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.config.MongodbConfig$.<init>(MongodbConfig.scala:72)
    at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.config.MongodbConfig$.<clinit>(MongodbConfig.scala)
    at TestMongoDB.MongoDB$.delayedEndpoint$TestMongoDB$MongoDB$1(MongoDB.scala:13)
```

but i got this error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi6F0.png)

Any help thanks

the error screen shot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi6F0.png)

Comment: I have used the following getting Exception https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67294454/getting-exception-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-in-spark-streaming-scala-mo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this also

```
import com.mongodb.spark.sql._
import com.mongodb.spark._
import org.bson.Document
import com.mongodb.spark.config._

def makeMongoURI(uri:String,database:String,collection:String) = (s"${uri}/${database}.${collection}")

val mongoURI = "mongodb://000.000.000.000:27017"
val Conf = makeMongoURI(mongoURI,"DBname","collectionname")

val readConfigintegra: ReadConfig = ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> Conf))


// Uses the ReadConfig
 val df3 = sqlContext.loadFromMongoDB(ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://000.000.000.000:27017/DBname.collectionname")))
```

from above code, you can read the mongo collection and store as Dataframe.

Comment: i did as you said please check in the update how i did it but i got the same exception

Comment: recompiling everything that depends on it. Do a clean build

Comment: would you please give me the maven dependencies references may be i have jars that are not compatible, which dependencies did you use ? thanks

Comment: share your error screen its working fine on my machine just put your ipaddress, db name and collection name and show the dataframe                 make sure you started mongodb check connection before run this code

Comment: please check the update i puted the screen shot of the error  ,just to let you know am u sing eclipse scala ide ,with apache spark 2.0.2, and i added spark mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.0.0 ,

Comment: may be there is some problem in your library please check the version or There are also some automatic tools to detect such changes:

1.japi-compliance-checker
2.japi-checker

Comment: please sorry to bother you but can you please tell me which dependencies or library did you use ,which spark version and what about mongoDB connector ,  Thanks a lot am grateful

Comment: i'm running on zeppelin .

Comment: I have used the following getting exception https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67294454/getting-exception-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-in-spark-streaming-scala-mo